# How can I play a video in flex in slow motion?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, video

Is there any way I can play a video using flex in slow motion?

Answer (score 1):

Get a function that Plays and Stops the Playhead really really fast ? Every few 100 ms ?

Never tried. If it lags ... definitely get FMS

Comment: If you aren't looking to use FMS, i second this. Just use the seek method of the flvplayback or whatever video mechanism you are using. Set a timer that slowly increments the seek position.

Answer (score 0):

easiest thing is to embed it into an swf (this can possibly be done automatically on the serverside). then you load it, and you can step through frame by frame (using MovieClip frame control methods). Or you can reduce the overall framerate of your app, which will cause the video to run slower.
However I am not sure about the effects this will have on audio.

greetz
back2dos

Comment: Lowering the framerate of the app won't affect video playback framerate.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching same thing some time ago. To have a slow motion in your video you Requires FMS 3.5.3 server.

For More Detail, go to this link. http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/features.html

Answer (score 0):

convert the video to swf, and lower the framerate, could be a solution. (not the best of course)